# For a column in Google Sheets, extract 2 top rows based on another column

Tags: excel, google-sheets

[Screenshot 1 of table as it starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TUP2.png)

Background: cities ranked on stats, but I am not looking at the city, simply at its country to see the top 2 for each country in a list with all others.

Using this example table, I am looking to pull out all values which are duplicate, and then find the top 2 for each duplicate based on stat 0. Removing not duplicates could be done manually.
Expected result:

[screenshot of a potential desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdaqc.png)

The extraction doesn't have to be in any particular order, I simply require the top 2 for each duplicate to be extracted based on stat 0, in any order.

This is done on a much larger sheet, so this is why it isn't feasible to do it manually.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far and why does it not deliver what you are looking to achieve?

Comment: Have tried various INDEX MATCH combinations, including INDEX MATCH with Large.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, you could try this in E2 pulled down to get the country either once or twice

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$11,MATCH(1,(COUNTIF(E1:E$1,A$2:A$11)<COUNTIF(A$2:A$11,A$2:A$11))*(COUNTIF(E1:E$1,A$2:A$11)<2),0)),"")
```

Then this in F2 to get the highest and second highest values

```
=IF(E2="","",LARGE(B$2:B$11*(A$2:A$11=E2),COUNTIF(E$1:E2,E2)))
```

must be entered as array formulas using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

This also works in Google sheets but the second formula needs to be declared as an array formula

```
=arrayformula(IF(E2="","",LARGE(B$2:B$11*(A$2:A$11=E2),COUNTIF(E$1:E2,E2))))
```